# Client on iPad accidentally adding <code> tag to posts while writing

Tags: tinymce, code

A client of mine complains that text gets 'randomly highlighted' when he is writing Wordpress posts on his iPad Pro. He uses the web interface.
I got him to stop deleting the 'highlighted' text and let me see it, and found out that it was caused by text he had written being enclosed in <code> tags.

How has he managed to accidentally type <code> tags, do you think? He is not a technical user and is certainly not doing it on purpose. Additionally he must be using the 'visual' rather than the 'text' editing mode, otherwise he would see the <code> tag instead of the 'highlighting'. And adding a <code> tag isn't even an option in that editing mode, that I can see.
Is there some clever shortcut for this that he is accidentally typing?

Failing this (and I really don't want to fail, ideally!!) is there some simple method I can teach him to clear all these tags?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a copy and paste issue.

Anyway, there is information on how to clean by allowing just certain tags in your written content in tinymce editor.
https://jonathannicol.com/blog/2015/02/19/clean-pasted-text-in-wordpress/

So if you go to disallow the `code` tag with this technique. You should be fine enough..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll ask, but I don't think my client uses copy/paste at all. Not kidding when I say he's 'not a technical user'!

Comment: Nope, he doesn't use copy and paste. These <code> tags appear while he's typing.

Comment: hmm.. maybe there is a custom TinyMCE shortcut, he is doing sometimes and accidentally adds code? (you already mentioned it in your question) like the default one [cmd + b] for bold. can just guess what caused it...